# Timer causes the form to exit immediately after running

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, timer

I am trying to show CPU and memory load in the statusbar of a MDI Form. The cpu and memory status are working correct if I just call them with a method. But now I want to make a Timer which continues updating two labels as long as the application is running:

```
public System.Threading.Timer MainTimer;
public System.Threading.TimerCallback MainTimerCallback;

private void InitializeTimer()
{
    MainTimerCallback = new System.Threading.TimerCallback(MainTimer_Tick);
    MainTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(MainTimerCallback,this,0,100);
}

private void MainTimer_Tick(object obj)
{
    UpdateSystemDiagnostics();
}
```

Then I code this in my MDI form constructor:

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    InitializeSystemDiagnostics();
    InitializeTimer();
}
```

This is for code for my diagnostics:

```
private PerformanceCounter _cpuLoad;
private PerformanceCounter _ramFree;
public float[] SystemDiagnostic = new float[2] { 0, 0 };

private void InitializeSystemDiagnostics()
{
    //Diagnostics
    _cpuLoad = new PerformanceCounter { CategoryName = "Processor", CounterName = "% Processor Time", InstanceName = "_Total" };
    _ramFree = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
}

private void UpdateSystemDiagnostics()
{
    SystemDiagnostic[0] = _cpuLoad.NextValue();
    SystemDiagnostic[1] = _ramFree.NextValue();

    _labelCpuStatus.Text = string.Format("CPU LOAD: ") + string.Format("{0:0.##}%", SystemDiagnostic[0]).PadRight(8);
    _labelMemoryStatus.Text = string.Format("FREE MEMORY: {0}MB", SystemDiagnostic[1]);
}
```

Why this cause the form to close as soon as I open it? Even if I hit debug it just opens and closes right away!

Also my other question is: Does this timer run on another thread? If I pass a time consuming operation to its Tick event, will it cause the UI to freeze or stutter?

**UPDATE**

When I put a breakpoint on this line:

```
_labelCpuStatus.Text = string.Format("CPU LOAD: ") + string.Format("{0:0.##}%", SystemDiagnostic[0]).PadRight(8);
```

I noticed that it works for like 2 or 3 times and it updates the label, but it quits with no warning or exception!

Comment: How are you running the form? i.e. `Program.cs` and `Main(...)`?

Comment: Just like a normal winform...yeah it runs through Program.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the form simply opens and closes immediately, it is likely you have an unhandled exception inside your constructor code. WinForms has an annoying habit of swallowing exceptions like this. If you Google around about it you should find some more information on it. You may be able to view the contents of this exception (if I am right in thinking that's the cause) by going to `Debug > Exceptions` and checking the box next to **Common Language Runtime Exceptions** under **Thrown**. This should break on all exceptions under that category.

As for whether the timer runs on another thread or not, best way to check is to add `Thread.Sleep(...some large number...)` in your handler for the `Tick` event (when your form is running) and see if it freezes the form. If so, it is running on the same thread.

**EDIT**

I've just had a quick look on MSDN and this is what I found about the threading of the timers:

[*System.Windows.Forms.Timer:*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx)

> A Timer is used to raise an event at user-defined intervals. This Windows timer is designed for a single-threaded environment where UI threads are used to perform processing. It requires that the user code have a UI message pump available and always operate from the same thread, or marshal the call onto another thread.

[*System.Threading.Thread.Timer*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)

> Use a TimerCallback delegate to specify the method you want the Timer to execute. The timer delegate is specified when the timer is constructed, and cannot be changed. The method does not execute on the thread that created the timer; it executes on a ThreadPool thread supplied by the system.

So if I am correct in my understanding; the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` executes on the UI thread (so will freeze the UI if performing long operations on it) and the `System.Threading.Thread.Timer` executes on a different thread to the UI (so shouldn't freeze the UI if performing long operations on it).

**Note: Just to clarify; I am not saying that the UI should be updated on another thread - instead, I am merely trying to illustrate the differences between the timers that had been noted. UI can only be updated on the UI thread. If long operations need to be performed without freezing the UI thread (that are independent of any UI elements), they can be performed on a separate thread and then the update of the UI can be invoked on the UI thread.**

Comment: Your last point is correct, but the OP specifically talks about updating the UI. You'd __want__ to do that from the UI thread.

Comment: Yes, you do. I was merely trying to illustrate the differences with the timers. You can, however, execute long operations (that are independent of any UI elements) on a separate thread, and call back to the UI thread to update the UI.

Comment: Yep, there are tons of variants :)

Comment: @codesparkle Thanks. I'm glad I managed to clarify what I was trying to explain.

Comment: So I didn't get what I have to do yet :D

Answer (score 3):

Use System.Windows.Forms.Timer instead of System.Threading.Timer
System.Threading.Timer runs it's fired event in another thread. But you can't change UI from another thread as you'll get cross thread operation exception.

Comment: But I heard that one uses the UI thread and causes the UI to be unresponsive. Am I wrong?

Comment: There's no other way of changing UI. Only from the UI thread. The only thing you SHOULD NOT NEVER DO is to make long calculations in the ui thread. Label text updates is ok and is the exact thing that is needed to be done in the UI thread

Comment: @Sean87 The `Forms.Timer` will _not_ cause the UI to be unresponsive between ticks. When it ticks and the method for that is called – it will. If that method is quick, though, there shouldn't be a problem. But best is – try a simple program with a `Forms.Timer`.

Answer (score 1):

if you want minimum changes you can add this to your code:

```
private void UpdateSystemDiagnostics()
{
    SystemDiagnostic[0] = _cpuLoad.NextValue();
    SystemDiagnostic[1] = _ramFree.NextValue();
 this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                _labelCpuStatus.Text = string.Format("CPU LOAD: ") + string.Format("{0:0.##}%", SystemDiagnostic[0]).PadRight(8);
    _labelMemoryStatus.Text = string.Format("FREE MEMORY: {0}MB", SystemDiagnostic[1]);
            }));

}
```